# Nesting subequations within align

Tags: amsmath, align, subequations

`subequations` seems to only work **outside** environments such as `align` and `equation`. What if I want to preserve the alignment of the equal signs using `align` while also would like `subequations` numbering within, such as:

```
\begin{align}
   \begin{subequations}
    A &= B+1 \\
    B+1 &= C
   \end{subequations}
\intertext{therefore}
   \begin{subequations}
    A &= C \\
    B &= C-1
   \end{subequations}
\end{align}
```

Which generates multitude of errors :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## The `subequations` environment & the `parentequation` counter

The original `subequations` environment redefines `\theparentequation` in a way that it is independent from the counter `parentequation`:

```
\protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
```

But we can redefine the `subequations` environment so that only the value of `equation` is saved and `\theparentequation` uses the counter `parentequation` again:

```
\def\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}%
```

But that way we would loose the setting of `\theequation` that might involve `\thechapter` in classes like `book`. For this, we could change it again manually to

```
\def\theparentequation{\thechapter.\arabic{parentequation}}%
```

### `etoolbox` and `\patchcmd`

Another approach uses [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and its `\patchcmd` macro.

First we let `\theparentequation` be the same as `\theequation`:

```
\let\theparentequation\theequation
```

After that we look for every ocurrence of `equation` and change it to `parentequation`:

```
\patchcmd{\theparentequation}{equation}{parentequation}{}{}
```

At this point we don't need the `\def`inition of `\theparentequation` inside the `subequations` environment anymore:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% let \theparentequation use the same definition as equation
\let\theparentequation\theequation
% change every occurence of "equation" to "parentequation"
\patchcmd{\theparentequation}{equation}{parentequation}{}{}

\renewenvironment{subequations}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
%  \def\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}% we patched it already :)
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
```

### `\nextParentEquation`

Let me also define the command `\nextParentEquation` that increments `parentequation` and resets `equation` so that we don't have to do this manually.

```
\newcommand*{\nextParentEquation}{%
  \stepcounter{parentequation}\setcounter{equation}{0}%
}
```

### Workaround for `parentequation` labels (by OP [Mobius Pizza](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9995/mobius-pizza))

While `\label` directly after `\begin{subequations}` works for referencing the first parent equation, to enable it to work after `\nextParentEquation` it is necessary to define a alias command `\parentlabel` for example, to evade sanitation performed by `amsmath`:

```
\let\parentlabel\label
```

#### Addition by Qrrbrbirlbel

I didn't think of labeling the parentequations, but with OP's addition (see above), I would even go a step further and redefine the `subequations` environment and the `\nextParentEquation` so that they take on optional argment, the label's name.

### Code

This MWE uses `report` with one `\chapter` to demonstrate that `\thechapter.` doesn't get lost while redefining the `subequations` environment, this also works with `article`, of course.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% let \theparentequation use the same definition as equation
\let\theparentequation\theequation
% change every occurence of "equation" to "parentequation"
\patchcmd{\theparentequation}{equation}{parentequation}{}{}

\renewenvironment{subequations}[1][]{%              optional argument: label-name for (first) parent equation
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
%  \def\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}% we patched it already :)
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%    parentequation = equation
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%                         (sub)equation  = 0
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}% 
  \let\parentlabel\label%                           Evade sanitation performed by amsmath
  \ifx\\#1\\\relax\else\label{#1}\fi%               #1 given: \label{#1}, otherwise: nothing
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%    equation = subequation
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\newcommand*{\nextParentEquation}[1][]{%            optional argument: label-name for (first) parent equation
  \refstepcounter{parentequation}%                  parentequation++
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%                         equation = 0
  \ifx\\#1\\\relax\else\parentlabel{#1}\fi%         #1 given: \label{#1}, otherwise: nothing
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\begin{equation}
  0 \neq 1
\end{equation}
\begin{subequations}[eq:2]% or: \label{eq:2}
\begin{align}%              or: \parentlabel{eq:2}
    A & = B+1 \label{eq:2a} \\
  B+1 & = C   \label{eq:2b}
\intertext{therefore}\nextParentEquation[eq:3]% or: \nextParentEquation\parentlabel{eq:3}
    A & = C   \label{eq:3a} \\
    B & = C-1 \label{eq:3b}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\eqref{eq:2}: \eqref{eq:2a}, \eqref{eq:2b} \\ \eqref{eq:3}: \eqref{eq:3a}, \eqref{eq:3b}
\begin{equation}
  1 \neq 2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: @MobiusPizza I've updated my answer with, hopefully, a “more elegant solution”.

Comment: Truly ingenious, wouldn't have been able to work that out myself, and great foresight on the possible issue with chapter counter. Many thanks!

Comment: I have improved the answer a bit by allowing labeling to work with the parent level, i.e. `parentequation`

Comment: @MobiusPizza Very good addition, I didn't even think of labeling the parent equation. I've updated my answer again with a solution I would use (the optional arguments), but YMMW.

Comment: Suggestion for your MWE: You can actually do everything inside one align environment if, for the “bare” equations that aren't subequations, you put `\tag{\theparentequation}` before the \\. This way you're guaranteed that they'll all line up, whether or not each one is actually meant to be a subequation.

Comment: This feels disappointingly complicated / hidden for such a simple-seeming thing... but thanks :)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Hi, the code from this answer has been very helpful and I have been using it in my work. Would you be willing to grant me a license to the code posted in this answer under the current LPPL (or even any compatible permissive license such as CC0)? I would like to put it in my personal LaTeX package where I collect math-mode snippets that I found useful. Since that package already contains code copied and modified from other existing packages it should be under LPPL so that I can legally "redistribute" (i.e., share with a handful of coauthors) it as one package.

Answer (score 8):

As you mentioned, use `subequations` *outside* the `align` environment and use some box manipulation to align the equations horizontally:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    A &= B+1 \\
    B+1 &= C
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\vspace*{-\belowdisplayshortskip}
\noindent therefore
\vspace*{-\abovedisplayshortskip}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    \phantom{B+1}\llap{$A$} &= C \\
    B &= C-1
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

The maximum length of the LHS of the top set of sub-equations is longer/wider than that of the bottom. So, we insert a `\phantom{<longest LHS>}\llap{$<LHS>$}` into the second set of sub-equations to make up for this horizontal difference in length.

The additional vertical adjustments make the representation more compact with the break of the short `therefore` text.

Comment: Thanks, alas I was looking for simple commands like `\addtocounter{parentequation}{1}` instead of alignment hacks like this, but that doesn't seem to work. I am guessing that is impossible to do. I will leave the question open if there are more elegant solutions.
IIRC `mathtools` also offers `\shortintertext` for more compact vertical spacing for `\intertext`

Comment: @MobiusPizza: I fully agree. [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` scans its contents more than once making some seemingly-easy modification hard to get around.