# Nesting subequations within align plus the usage of cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, subequations

I am using the solution for nested subequations with alignment (“**[The `subequations` environment & the `parentequation` counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80146)**”). I would like to use `cleveref` package references with groups of subequations defined by `\nextParentEquation` command, but then I end up with “??” instead of “eq.” prefix.

Does anyone know how could this problem be solved?

MWE and image are below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\theparentequation\theequation % let \theparentequation use the same definition as equation
\patchcmd{\theparentequation}{equation}{parentequation}{}{} % change every occurence of "equation" to "parentequation"
\renewenvironment{subequations}[1][]{%              optional argument: label-name for (first) parent equation
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    %  \def\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}% we patched it already
    \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%    parentequation = equation
    \setcounter{equation}{0}%                         (sub)equation  = 0
    \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}% 
    \let\parentlabel\label%                           Evade sanitation performed by amsmath
    \ifx\\#1\\\relax\else\label{#1}\fi%               #1 given: \label{#1}, otherwise: nothing
    \ignorespaces
}{%
    \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%    equation = subequation
    \ignorespacesafterend
}
\newcommand*{\nextParentEquation}[1][]{%            optional argument: label-name for (first) parent equation
    \refstepcounter{parentequation}%                  parentequation++
    \setcounter{equation}{0}%                         equation = 0
    \ifx\\#1\\\relax\else\parentlabel{#1}\fi%         #1 given: \label{#1}, otherwise: nothing
}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{Equations:}

\begin{subequations} \label{eq:1}%
    Below are two main equations divided into three sub-equations:\\
    first:
    \begin{align}
    0+1 &= 1\text{,} \tag{\ref*{eq:1}} \\
    \intertext{second:} \nextParentEquation[eq:2]
    100+100 &= 200\text{,} \label{eq:2a} \\
    \intertext{and third:}
    10000+20000 &= 30000\text{.} \label{eq:2b}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\section*{References to equations:}

\texttt{cref}: \cref{eq:1} vs \texttt{ref}: eq.~(\ref{eq:1}).\\
\textbf{\texttt{cref}: \cref{eq:2}} vs \texttt{ref}: eq.~(\ref{eq:2}).\\
\texttt{cref}: \cref{eq:2a} vs \texttt{ref}: eq.~(\ref{eq:2a}).\\
\texttt{cref}: \cref{eq:2b} vs \texttt{ref}: eq.~(\ref{eq:2b}).

\end{document}
```

[image: Example document presenting the problem.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cleveref` maintains `\cref@X@name` and `\cref@X@nameplural` for the cross reference information, where `X` is the counter name.

If `\cref@parentequation@name` is not defined, it will display the warning on compilation and `??` in the text.

In order to get the correct cross-reference name, use

`\crefname{parentequation}{equation}{equations}` and `\Crefname{parentequation}{Equation}{Equations}` for lower and uppercase usage of `\cref` and `\Cref.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\theparentequation\theequation % let \theparentequation use the same definition as equation
\patchcmd{\theparentequation}{equation}{parentequation}{}{} % change every occurence of "equation" to "parentequation"
\renewenvironment{subequations}[1][]{%              optional argument: label-name for (first) parent equation
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    %  \def\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}% we patched it already
    \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%    parentequation = equation
    \setcounter{equation}{0}%                         (sub)equation  = 0
    \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}% 
    \let\parentlabel\label%                           Evade sanitation performed by amsmath
    \ifx\\#1\\\relax\else\label{#1}\fi%               #1 given: \label{#1}, otherwise: nothing
    \ignorespaces
}{%
    \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%    equation = subequation
    \ignorespacesafterend
}
\newcommand*{\nextParentEquation}[1][]{%            optional argument: label-name for (first) parent equation
    \refstepcounter{parentequation}%                  parentequation++
    \setcounter{equation}{0}%                         equation = 0
    \ifx\\#1\\\relax\else\parentlabel{#1}\fi%         #1 given: \label{#1}, otherwise: nothing
}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{parentequation}{equation}{equations}
\Crefname{parentequation}{Equation}{Equations}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{Equations:}

\begin{subequations} \label{eq:1}%
    Below are two main equations divided into three sub-equations:\\
    first:
    \begin{align}
    0+1 &= 1\text{,} \tag{\ref*{eq:1}} \\
    \intertext{second:} \nextParentEquation[eq:2]
    100+100 &= 200\text{,} \label{eq:2a} \\
    \intertext{and third:}
    10000+20000 &= 30000\text{.} \label{eq:2b}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\section*{References to equations:}

\texttt{cref}: \cref{eq:1} vs \texttt{ref}: eq.~(\ref{eq:1}).\\
\textbf{\texttt{cref}: \cref{eq:2}} vs \texttt{ref}: eq.~(\ref{eq:2}).\\
\texttt{cref}: \cref{eq:2a} vs \texttt{ref}: eq.~(\ref{eq:2a}).\\
\texttt{cref}: \cref{eq:2b} vs \texttt{ref}: eq.~(\ref{eq:2b}).

\end{document}
```