# How to interrupt sequential numbering for equations once, then continue the sequence after?

Tags: equations, labels

I am using TeXstudio with MiKTeX. I am new to LaTeX but have the standard packages like Amsmath.

I would like to have the following numbering scheme for my equations

```
eq 1
eq 2
eq 3a
eq 3b
eq 3c
eq 4
eq 5
```

Where I have interrupted the normal sequential counting with 3a, 3b, and 3c, but the sequence resumed with eq 4 afterward. Furthermore, I would like to do this in an automated fashion, i.e. if I go back and insert another equation

```
eq 1
eq 2
<---insert new equation
eq 3a
eq 3b
eq 3c
eq 4
eq 5
```

then the numbering scheme will automatically update to

```
eq 1
eq 2
eq 3
eq 4a
eq 4b
eq 4c
eq 5
eq 6
```

Is there a way to do this, or a reference I can read about how to do this? Thanks!

#### Edit solved

as per the comment, I used subequations.

```
\begin{subequations}[eq:sp]
\begin{align}
equation math \label{eq:spa}\\
equation math \label{eq:spb}\\
equation math \label{eq:spc}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

worked for me. The "sp" was arbitrary; it seems to be a tag for the remaining subequations.

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80146/190043) was helpful.

Comment: see the subequations environment in amsmath

Comment: Please post your own solution as an answer instead of an edit to your question. That way you can (later) mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment, I used subequations to accomplish what I was looking for.

```
\begin{subequations} \label{eq:sp}
\begin{align}
{}& equation math \label{eq:spa}\\
{}& equation math \label{eq:spb}\\
{}& equation math \label{eq:spc}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

worked for me. The "sp" was arbitrary; <s>it seems to be a tag for the remaining subequations</s> (corrected in comment below). {}& was to left align the equations.

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80146/190043) was helpful.

Comment: your comment about `sp` seems a little strange, `\label` has no effect on the numbering of this equation, and the whole `eq:spb` string is arbitrary and could equally be `\label{wibble}`  it allows you to reference the equation from elsewhere with `\eqref{eq:spb}` (or \eqref{wibble}` )