# How to align subequations within table

Tags: tables, align, amsmath, nesting

I would like to reproduce the structure, alignment, and numbering, of the equations in this table:

[image]

I have tried many combinations of the environments equation, subequation, align, table / tabular, tried Mathpix snip, and referenced related question [Nesting subequations within align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80134/nesting-subequations-within-align), but have not been able to find a solution, mainly due to my inexperience with LaTeX.

Could you please help me reproduce this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `subequations` and two `minipage`s, each with its own `align` environment. Note that to keep the vertical spacing equal in the two minipages I added a `\vphantom` fraction to each of the left equations so they had the same height as the right equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{subequations}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \begin{align}
    \nabla\cdot\vec E\vphantom{\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}} &= \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}, \\
    \nabla\cdot\vec B\vphantom{\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}} &= 0,
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}% <-- % symbol necessary
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
  \begin{align}
    \nabla\times\vec E &= -\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}, \\
    \nabla\times\vec B &= \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}+\mu_0\vec j,
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{subequations}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I set the left `minipage` at 40% of `\textwidth`, and the right at 60%, but you can adjust to your liking.